# Pronunciation of 七々々 in this name?

Tags: pronunciation

In an anime, 龍ヶ嬢七々々 is pronounced as りゅうがじょう ななな. I'm wondering why 七々々 is prounounced as ななな, since 七 is なな, and there are two repeat signs.

Is this some sort of special case where 七 is prounounced as just な and hence with the two repeat signs becomes ななな? Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many kanji dictionaries list name readings separate from 音 and 訓 readings.  When I look up 七 in 新漢語林, I see the following readings listed under names:

> かず
>   しち
>   **な**
>   なな

So yes, I think in this case each one is read な, although *most* of the time outside of names it is not read as simply な, and it may not always be read that way inside a name, either.